# How can I anchor this tkinter label correctly using anchor = "n"

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

So basically I want to anchor this label to "n" correctly, it keeps being anchored in the centre when I clearly want it on n or on top of the page. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
from tkinter import *
import time
import webbrowser
import random

    label_frame = tk.Frame(root)
answer_label = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Hello! Type '/help' to get a list of all functions!", font=(30))
answer_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label_frame.place(anchor = 'n')
```

As you can tell the code is a bit out of context but I just need to anchor `answer_label` to the top correctly using anchor="n".

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to use `anchor="n"`, why haven't you tried it? Also, "correctly" is not very precise. We don't know what you think a correct placement is. Centered? All the way to the right? All the way to the left? Something else? What you've done will put the label at the top. Are you asking how to use `pack` or `grid` instead of `place`?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry for not clarifying, The anchor n isn't really working. I want someone to see what's wrong with the line.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line syntactically. It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Context matters greatly when doing layout. If you want the label at the top, `pack` is usually better than place, but grid works as well. However, it really depends on what else you plan on doing in the window.  `place` can work as well if you use relative placement, but normally one of the others is better.